# Apply color to clicked table row

Tags: javascript

i have this function to detect when i click on a table row. I want it to turn the clicked on row a certain colour and remove the active class from all other rows. Currently it just makes every row i click on red without removing the colour from the other rows.

html:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var tbodyRows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];

tbody.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    tbodyRows.classList.remove('active');
    target.classList.add('active');
}
```

js:

```
<table id="data">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th class="number" style="text-align:center">#</th>
            <th class="time" style="text-align:center">time</th>
            <th class="artist">artist</th>
            <th class="song">song</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="song-data"></tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Keep book of the clicked row in a variable declared in the same scope as the function. Notice, that when using `classList` you don't need the complex event property checker, and you can also use `closest` instead of the `while` loop.

Comment: @Teemu when i declare the variable as the previous one how am i meant to then remove the active class from it the first time?

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLqnxe0d/).

Comment: Thank you! this helps

Answer (score 1):

You aren't possible to remove all the color from the other rows, because you are not deleting the other rows **classes**, you are only deleting one, I think a better way to show you is doing it, so I did this (I also think you can refactor a little more):

```js
const table = document.getElementById('data');
let tableBody = table.querySelector('tbody');

tableBody.onclick = function (e) {
    let tableRows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
    let target = e.target.parentNode;
    
    while (target.nodeName !== 'TR') {
      target = target.parentNode;
    }
    
    tableRows.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove('active');
    });
    
    target.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="data">
    <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th class="number" style="text-align:center">#</th>
        <th class="time" style="text-align:center">time</th>
        <th class="artist">artist</th>
        <th class="song">song</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="song-data">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This also won't work with dynamic tables. Also, if the cells contain elements, `e.target.parentNode` doesn't refer to the row, it refers to a content element or cell instead.

Comment: Yep, you are totally right, I made it now with a little while, I didn't see that it was a dynamic table, but what do you mean that it won't work with dynamic tables?, I was thinking while fetching the date to the table rows, it will also be a `TR`, the event is in the `TBody` not the tr, maybe if you can clarify that or make a little explanation @Teemu

Comment: An empty tbody often indicates, that it is filled later, and when that happens, `table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')` won't contain the new rows. Also, iterating the table in the event handler is a bit like you picked a scuttle of apples, then bring the scuttle home, and throw away all the apples but the first you picked in the garden ...

Comment: Ok, yes, you are right in the querySelector, it's outside of the event scope, but how should be a good approach for this?, I mean I was thinking in a `nodeList` but this will remain in the same because you need to iterate to know the `nodeName`

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle I've linked in the comment thread below the question.

Comment: Cool man will do

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Notice how tBodyRows now references all table rows (removed the `[0]`) and how we iterate over it with `forEach()`.

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var tbodyRows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

tbody.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }    

    Array.from(tbodyRows).forEach(elem => {
        elem.classList.remove('active')
    })
    
    
    target.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: you're right, tbodyRows should then be updated on each click